# Ubuntu - Windows file sharing

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing

**Scenario:**
  I have a folder on Ubuntu which I want to share over a network (LAN). This folder has many sub-folders and lots of files (~10k). The client is running on Windows Xp. This client will frequently modify these files. The network has some disturbances, so the client gets disconnected for that period. That is why I want some caching/copy of that folder on client side, so when the network comes up both folder will be synced.

Till now I have thought of 2 solutions:

1. Samba server on Ubuntu
2. scheduled rsync

Is there any other option?

I would prefer a copy of that folder on client machine. So even if the network/server goes down, I'll have something to work on. Here the main problem is network disturbance. I don't want the client to get hanged when the connection goes down.

Comment: "Unison" is probably more suitable than rsync, if you might ever modify the files on the server. I'm not aware of a caching network filesystem, it's one of those problems that's harder than it looks to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good suggestion by pjc50. Read more about Unison at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison

Comment: Perfect!!! That's what I wanted! Thank you pcj50 & Sam.